# How Would You Enqueue A Google Web Font?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm using the [Rosario font](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Rosario) from the [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) in my theme and I want to [enqueue the font](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) so that if there was ever a plugin that used a fancy font that there wouldn't be any conflicts or wasted bandwidth.

I want to use the Normal 400, Normal 400 Italic, and Bold 700 in my theme. How should I enqueue the font? Is it worth including the last font variant in case the other script uses it?

Several options I've been thinking about:

- Single

  ```
  wp_register_style( 'rosario', "http://..." );
  ```
- Combined with Handle

  ```
  wp_register_style( 'rosario_400_400-italic_700', "http://..." );
  ```
- ALL together

  ```
  wp_register_style( 'rosario_400', "http://..." );
  wp_register_style( 'rosario_400-italic', "http://..." );
  wp_register_style( 'rosario_700', "http://..." );`
  ```

The third option looks the most explicit and but the multiple calls for same font will probably be more inefficient than simply loading the font twice.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to just use `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario:400,700,400italic` which is the "combined" URL given by Google when selecting multiple weights/styles of a font. You can then just register the font once. You don't need to over-complicate the `$handle` either, something like `google-fonts-rosario` should do just fine as long as it is unique as mentioned in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style).

Comment: What about the off chance someone wants to use 700 italic that I didn't include? If I'm declaring that I've included Rosario should that imply _all_ font variants?

Comment: While I may not understand your original use-case, there is a bit of assumption that goes along with using custom web fonts. When someone includes `Arial`, it's safe to assume that they have access to every variant of the font, bold, italics, bold italics, etc., but those are system fonts - it doesn't hinder your website to load these variants as with Arial, it is assumed to be available. With custom fonts, "you" decide what's available (as that effects page-load based on the number of variants and the design). The URL query vars while not plain-text should help users decide what is available

Comment: Thanks @Zach! For now I'll probably just include all of the font variants even though it increases the page load. In the future I may look into a way to separate out the font variants so that each plugin/theme only has to DL the variants it needs.

Comment: You could also combine more font families in the same request by separating them with a "|" for example: fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:700|Rosario:400,400italic,700,700italic

Answer (score -1):

Go to google fonts and on the font you want select 'quick use' next to the 'add to collection' button. There are three ways to do what you are looking for very easily JS, @import and standard. You can just select the different weights and styles and Google spits out the code to insert.

Standard looks like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

@import looks like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario:400,400italic,700,700italic);
```

You can grab the url that google creates for those in the wp_register_style function. The link below is an example.

http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Montserrat+Alternates:400,700

Comment: The question was asking about `enqueue` and his use of `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style`.

Comment: My fault, I didn't word that well. The method for retrieving the web address found in both of the other methods for use with wp_register_style is the real point; you can use the link I attached to have google give you the proper url the question was seeking.